# SSRS 2005 with ASP.NET Report Viewer

Tags: css, asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Hi unfortunately we only have **SQL Server 2005** so I am stuck with SSRS 2005. I have created a report and runs as expected.

I have an issue though. When I combine it with the **Microsoft Report Viewer** it's width is shrunk. I have noticed this comes back to normal if I force my app to use **IE7** however then i'm on a whole totally different issue with the site not looking quite right and some of the Ajax functionality does not work slickly as I would like it. Is there anything I can do?

Looking at the HTML it looks as if the SSRS report is adding a table and a column after my report. Can anyone help remove this, as it does not look professional?

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in your report's textboxes (or other objects) to have

```
.CanGrow = false
.CanShrink = false
```

Comment: Hi That has made no difference, can anybody help. I have noticed that this may not be due to Report viewer as when I export my SSRS report it also has put an extra column at the end of my report. This is causing the report to be centered left rather than in the middle.

Comment: Then your problem is outside SSRS2005. I suggest you look at the web page internally using Inspector or FireFly and see what is manipulating your report and see if you can alter the HTML or javascripts asssociated with the screen surrounding your report. Good luck @altaaf.hussein